# Retrieve data froma webpage using jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a web page and I'm interested in find the value of id r2.

This is my webpage:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span id="r2">0,7102</span><b style="color: #00B000; font-weight: bold;">lorem ipsus</b></li>
  <li><span id="r1">0,6999</span>macche</li>
  <li><span id="s1">0,6896</span>addoca</li>
  <li><span id="s2">0,6828</span><b style="color: #B00000; font-weight: bold;">te ne frica</b></li>
</ul>
<br>
<button id="button" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<input type="text" id="r1">
```

How can I find the value 0,7102 of the r2 id using jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see that you are adding Text to the page. Is that not working? What is it you are trying to do? What error do you encounter? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please also provide an example of the `data`.

Comment: I have updated your Code Example into a Snippet.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quicly reply...I deleted my jquery code because it doesn't gives to me any result...could you please tell me the correct code please?

Comment: you got two elements with the same `id` ... this is incorrect (`input` and `span`)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function(e) {
    $("#r3").val($("#r2").text());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span id="r2">0,7102</span><b style="color: #00B000; font-weight: bold;">lorem ipsus</b></li>
  <li><span id="r1">0,6999</span>macche</li>
  <li><span id="s1">0,6896</span>addoca</li>
  <li><span id="s2">0,6828</span><b style="color: #B00000; font-weight: bold;">te ne frica</b></li>
</ul>
<br>
<button id="button" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<input type="text" id="r3">
```

This is using the `.text()` as a Getter to get the Text Node from the selected element.

Comment: I guess this is too hard for the beginner and he expects it to land in the input. And by the way there is a duplicate `id` that is wrong.

Comment: @FlashThunder I had not caught that. Thanks for that. Fixed it up a bit.

Comment: Hi the webpage is extenal like http://www.dorso.com/theria.html

Comment: @thisisatestnull sorry that does not make sense. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example